# I'm trying to make a very simple hangman program work. The while loop isn't working

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf

PLEASE HELP. I've spent hours trying to find the problem to no avail. It works perfectly until I get to the while loop and then it seems to process the user's guess with a one loop delay.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define WORD_COUNT 8
#define MAX_LENGTH 10

typedef char string[MAX_LENGTH];

void main(void) {

    string words[WORD_COUNT] = { "lion", "tiger", "dog", "cat", "pig", "mouse",
            "fish", "b ird" };

    char answer[MAX_LENGTH];
    char guess;
    int count = -5, index, i, found, choice = -7;
    char mysteryWord[MAX_LENGTH];

    printf("Welcome to Hangman!\n");

    printf("\n\nChoose an option\n"
            "1) Easy\n"
            "2) Moderate\n"
            "3) Hard\n"

            "Your choice: ");

    scanf("%i", &choice);
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        count = 5;
        break;
    case 2:
        count = 3;
        break;
    case 3:
        count = 1;

    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    index = rand() % WORD_COUNT;

    strcpy(mysteryWord, words[index]);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(mysteryWord); i = i + 1)

    {
        answer[i] = '-';
    }

    answer[i] = '\0';

    printf("%s \n", answer);

    while (1 > 0) {
        printf("\n %i guess(es) left\n", count);
        printf("Guess a letter:");
        scanf("%c\n", &guess);
        guess = tolower(guess);
        /* found is a "flag" variable. When found = 0 (false) we */
        /* haven't found a match, and later, if we find a match, */
        /* change found = 1; (true)  */
        found = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(mysteryWord); ++i) /*or i++ */
        {
            if (mysteryWord[i] == guess) {
                answer[i] = guess;
                found = 1;
            }
        }
        if (found == 0) {
            printf("Not found!\n");
            --count;
        } /* or --count or count=count-1 */

        if (count == 0) {
            printf("Sorry, game over.\n");
            printf("The answer is %s.", mysteryWord);
            break; /* or return;? */
        }

        else {
            /* try instead if(answer==mysteryWord) */
            if (strcmp(answer, mysteryWord) == 0) 
            {
                printf("Yes, it's a %s\n"
                        "Congratulations!\n", answer);
                break; /* or return */
            } else
                printf("%s", answer);
        }
    } /* end of while loop */

} /* end of main */
```

Here's an example running in linux terminal. The problem I believe lies in how the letter guessed gets processed one loop after the user inputs the letter.

Welcome to Hangman!

Choose an option
1) Easy
2) Moderate
3) Hard

### Your choice: 1

5 guess(es) left
Guess a letter:p

### Not found!

4 guess(es) left
Guess a letter:c

### Not found!

3 guess(es) left
Guess a letter:d

### Not found!

2 guess(es) left
Guess a letter:o
d--
2 guess(es) left
Guess a letter:g
do-
2 guess(es) left
Guess a letter:g
Yes, it's a dog
Congratulations!

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: `scanf("%c\n", &guess);` --> `scanf(" %c", &guess);`  Add space drop \n

Comment: It must be something in your code. My `while` loops are functioning perfectly, broadly speaking.

Comment: To debug this yourself, put `printf("You guessed '%c'\n", guess);` right after the `scanf` to see what is really going on.

Comment: It's incredibly sad and disheartening to see that devs have to be led by the nose to do even printf() debugging.

Comment: ' I've spent hours trying to find the problem to no avail'; am I the only one who finds this tale tragic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 'PLEASE HELP' shouting and no attempt to debug.

Comment: Thanks this is my first post. You guys were mostly helpful. What is a dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `scanf("%i", &choice);` statement is executed, it puts the integer entered by the user, into the `int` variable `choice`.  However, it also leaves the newline character in the input buffer causing the user input to get thrown off.  When the `scanf("%c\n", &guess);` statement is executed, the next character entered is placed on the input buffer, but the `%c` only causes one character (the newline character) to be read from the buffer, while the character the user entered is still on the buffer.  Because there's a newline character after the %c in the format string, the newline character that would have followed it is discarded (because it matches the next newline).  On subsequent iterations the previous character still on the buffer is then read.

The recommended solution is to insert a single space before the `%c` like this: `scanf(" %c", &guess)`.  When scanf is executed, the single space will cause it to ignore all other whitespace characters until the first non-whitespace character, which in this case means the newline still on the buffer will be read and ignored.

Comment: Thank you. You explain things very well.